# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a issue with Angular 2. When i want to start server it get this:

```
$ ng serve
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
at Class.run (C:\Users\Damien\Desktop\application\node_modules\@angul ar\cli\tasks\serve.js:22:63)
at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (C:\Users\Damien\Desktop\application\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:103:26)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

I reinstalled CLI and nothing else is working. I could be something with json file?

Comment: Seems like a problem in your code.  You have something that has a property called `config`.  Let's call it `Foo`, so it might look like this:  `class Foo { public config: any; };`  Then somewhere else you're trying to get the value of `config`, maybe like this: `let f = getFoo();  let c = f.config;`  The problem is `f` is `null`.

Comment: Did any of the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 50):

I found the solution!
In my case I moved the project to another directory.
there is a hidden file called **.angular-cli**
Show the hidden file in the old project and copy this file and paste it in the new distention. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: if the issue persists and provided that you are in the root folder of your project, try run ( on . UNIX ) `cp src/tsconfig.app.json src/tsconfig.json`

Comment: In case you have removed old directory, try @carnaru-valentin answer, it works!

Answer (score 36):

Probably you remove project into other folder, or delete .angular-cli.json

Into the root of your app, add:
.angular-cli.json

and paste:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "PROJECT_NAME"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should i put this file? i mean on which path?

Comment: According to follow your instruction. But getting this issue ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\test\petmatrix-pro-ng5-master\src\tsconfig.app.json'

Answer (score 10):

Please add following file at root folder File Name-.angular-cli.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "XXXX"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "assets/css/styles.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
                "assets/js/project.js"      

            ],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks Krishna.

Answer (score 5):

you missing .angular-cli.json,

you can generate it by(go to a new folder)

```
 ng new project-name
```

now copy .angular-cli.json file to your project root.

```
 ng serve
```

the error should be gone.

Answer (score 4):

this error is coming due to removal of **.angular-cli.json** so first add this on root folder.
if after that still get error then check static file in .angular-cli.json

Answer (score 2):

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

> Step 3: Serve the application Go to the **project directory** and
>   launch the server.
>
> content_copy
>   **cd my-app** 
>   ng serve --open

May be you missed the point 3 (cd my-app)?
The start directory have been like: ./my-app/my-app.
If start application from other directory we get this error.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to update Angular CLI by following these instructions [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update). This topic is covered a bit [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736). The usual culprit is an update of Angular CLI without following the above instructions, but you don't give any specifics on your situation.

Comment: I have removed "." from angular-cli.json and it is still not working. I have updated the CLI as you describe
      
      exports.CLI_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'angular-cli.json';

Comment: What did you do before this issue began?

Comment: Removing the "." is not a solution. It was a step to diagnosing the problem for one user with that issue. I don't recommend that you change anything. What I recommend is that you uninstall and reinstall angular cli carefully following the instructions [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update).

Comment: ok so i was setting my our apps, new components. it was working fine then i found some interesting opensource project in angular so i clone it and try to run it locally. that's all story

Comment: my other projects run as expected just checked

Comment: Post your Angular CLI version in your answer. (You can get that with `ng -v`.) Then post the package.json and angular-cli.json files of the project in question.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure You are inside the project folder. This may happen when the programmer has a folder for Practice purpose for eg: says "MyWorkOuts" folder.
in which the programmer may have lot of practice app says:practice1,practice2,etc...

I use VS code
in which make sure the terminal is in the exact angular application you try to start.

this may look simple or even silly. But while learning all happens. 
after making sure you may follow the other solutions of our stackoverflow friends.

Thank You guys Good Day :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be a mising file `.angular-cli.json`, do not forget the extension `.json` which implies the file format. Copy this file from the original project and paste it into your currrent project.

Answer (score -1):

http://javasampleapproach.com/aws/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-how-to-upload-file-to-s3-bucket

in your tsconfig.app.json file put this

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": ["node"] 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```