# Cannot read property 'config' of null

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler

I am new in angular2. I have downloaded angular 2 project and tried to setup. I installed angular cli 1.0.0-rc.2 and when I am doing ng serve it is showing the below error:

> Cannot read property 'config' of null TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'config' of null
>       at Class.run (D:\Sumit\AgulaNew\admin\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:22:63)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (D:\Sumit\AgulaNew\admin\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:103:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: Does whatever you are trying to read 'config' from exist in your system? ie, if it is part of a json object, do you have that stored somewhere it can read it?

Comment: It is inside @angular cli modules

Comment: Then something might not have installed correctly. What version of node are you using? And if you are new to angular 2 have you considered starting with an angular 4 tutorial and set up instead?

Comment: i am using node v8.5.0 and npm  5.3.0... and this was an existing big project.

Comment: Could you try updating the cli? I don't know that is what is wrong but it looks like you are running newer versions of node and npm but cli is a little old.

Comment: No, I have not try yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Cannot read property 'config' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835118/angular-2-cannot-read-property-config-of-null)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error this morning.

You probably copied your project from one folder to another using Finder or Explorer. If so, the file `.angular-cli.json` is missing.

If you are using a Mac, use the command `ls -a` to list hidden files. You will notice that `.angular-cli.json` will be there. Just copy the file to the new location and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

I once git cloned a project where

```
ng -serve
```

failed.

This was because `.angular-cli.json` was missing.

On the other and

```
npm start
```

did the job instead ;-)

Typically the project from angular tutorial [webpack guide](https://angular.io/guide/webpack)
downloadable from
[webpack.zip](https://angular.io/generated/zips/webpack/webpack.zip)
confirms the case

Answer (score 2):

`Cannot read property 'config' of null` is a typical error when `.angular-cli.json` is missing.

BTW you do not need any seed projects as a `base` for your new app and there is no reason to use outdated `angular cli 1.0.0-rc.2` as you mention.

Check the latest releases https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases or with `npm show @angular/cli version` then install the latest `npm install -g @angular/cli` and generate a [new project](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/new.md) with that. To see your local CLI version run `ng -v`

Also checkout the recent article [The Past, Present, and Future of the Angular CLI](https://blog.angular.io/the-past-present-and-future-of-the-angular-cli-13cf55e455f8) by one of the core Angular team mebers @StephenFluin